# Is it possible to control each "JOB" in MySql (MariaDB)?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm curious.
ORACLE allows you to operate with JOB's BROKEN.
I wonder if MYSQL can control JOB (EVENT) individually like ORALCE.

EX ) ORACLE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFXVR.png)

MySql ???

Comment: Welcome!  Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: You may enable or disable an event. [ALTER EVENT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-event.html).

Comment: It's not always the case that mysql experts are also oracle experts - you could broaden your audience by explaining your requirement without reference to other technologies.